# How to Sign out user using Google+ API?

Tags: c#, wpf, google-api, google-plus

I have been developing a desktop application in C#(WPF) using Google+ APIs.It's a simple application that provides a login page for Googleplus+, when user enters credentials & consents the application's permission request,it retrieve and display the User's profile information.

Using the Google+ API I am able to retrieve the User's Profile information from Google+.
But when I exit and open the application again, instead of login page it is going directly to the "**Request for approval**" page.

The problem is in Internet Explorer,as it enables the **"Stay signed in"** option by default.I want to logout the user automatically every time the application closes.

After searching in google, I found by navigating the browser to this "https://accounts.google.com/Logout?&continue=http://www.google.com/" logout the user.

Is there any API in google+ for logging out programmatically the user or is this the only way?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google+ API doesnt provide any methods to log a user out of the Google's single sign-on, because it shouldnt be handled at the layer of Google+ API.

Google+ authorize and authenticate you with an access token that is gathered by your auth flow that needs a signed-in Google account. If you want to log the user out of Google network, you should redirect him/her to

```
https://accounts.google.com/Logout?&continue=[nextUrl]
```

or clear all of the cookies on launch or shutdown.

If you want to revoke the access token you retrieved for your application, you should use https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke that will expire the existing access token.

Answer (score 2):

Google+ do not provide any api for signout or rather they didnt worked for me.

i found out other solution which i am mentioning here try this out.
it worked out for me.

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue='your site url'
```